# Why is request.environ.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', request.remote_addr) not returning the right address sometimes?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, replit

I have a flask-based webpage running on repl.it. In said website, i have a form which uses post to send data to a page of the site.

On this page, i have the following python code:

```
b = request.environ.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', request.remote_addr)
```

which should return (clientip, proxy1, proxy2) as it does on every other page on the website i use it on, however it simply returns only proxy2. I've looked through `request.envrion` and theres no occurence of the client's ip adress at all. Why is this? Why does it work on other pages of the site but not here?

How do i get `request.envrion` to contain the client IP on this page? Is there some alternative to `request.envrion` that i can use to get the client ip?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
headers_list = request.headers.getlist("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
http_x_real_ip = request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP', request.remote_addr)

ip_address = headers_list[0] if headers_list else http_x_real_ip
```